# Android Studio cannot find device

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk

I have enabled `Developer Options` on my phone, I have `rebooted my computer`, `switched USB ports`, relaunched Android Studio and yet Android Studio still cannot find my `Samsung Galaxy Note 3`. I have installed the `SDK for API 19` for the phone, and enabled `ADB integration`.

When I plug my phone into the computer, it says `"Connected as a media device"`. It also shows up in Other Devices as `SAMSUNG_ANDROID` and I installed the drivers for it.

Sometimes Android Studio says that the ADB or something is not compatible although I forgot to copy the message. I have tried to crack this for a couple of hours now and looked through everything with no success because Android Studio still shows it up as "No Connected Devices".

I am on Windows 8.

Before the phone would show up in file explorer when android studio could find it but now it doesn't show up in android studio and the phone will not pop up in file explorer. What a coincidence.

Comment: have you installed samsung kies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under developer options, check *Enable USB Debugging.* Then, unplug and replug your phone. After a few seconds the phone should have a dialog box asking you to confirm the computer's fingerprint. Do so.

If that box never pops up, you probably have a driver issue.

Comment: That box doesn't show up but I installed the driver from Samsung website.